# Can gravitational waves be absorbed near a quasar?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, quasars

As the [Quasar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) Wikipedia article explains, a quasar is powered by gas falling into a supermassive black hole at the center of a galaxy. The [Luminous infrared galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_infrared_galaxy) article says that, in extreme cases, the radiated energy is larger than the [Eddington Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_luminosity) permits. The article mentions some possible mechanisms.

Recently LIGO observed a merger of two black holes. 3 solar masses was converted to gravitational radiation in a fraction of a second. If some of that gravitational radiation could be converted to other forms of energy, this might be another way to generate more power than you would expect.

But as discussed in [Where does gravitational waves' energy go?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235574/37364), this is not likely. Gravitational waves couple very weakly to matter.

But near a quasar, there can be enough hot gas to push the Eddington limit. In this environment, is there any realistic mechanism that would convert gravitational waves to electromagnetic radiation? E.G. Would a gravitational wave compress the gas, making it hotter and radiate more? Magnetic fields can be very strong near a black hole. Can gravitational waves do work against them?

Comment: See Teukolsky and Press, http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1974ApJ...193..443T/0000443.000.html