# Do objects absorb or reflect gravitational waves?

Tags: gravity, scattering, gravitational-waves

We all know that objects can absorb and reflect electromagnetic waves.  It stands to reason the same might be true for gravitational waves.

Comment: The general term is “scatter”, not “reflect”, for what happens to the parts of the wave that are not absorbed.

Comment: There is extremely little interaction, unless the gravitational wave encounters a black hole. See [Can gravitational waves be absorbed near a quasar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354698/37364) and links therein.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, objects can scatter and absorb gravitational waves.

For example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3805) considers the scattering and absorption of gravitational plane waves by rotating black holes.

And [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237168/how-much-energy-does-the-earth-absorb-when-a-gravitational-wave-passes-through-i/504103#504103) discusses how much energy the Earth absorbs when a gravitational wave passes through it. (It’s miniscule.)

Historically, [Feynman’s sticky bead argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bead_argument) helped settle early controversies over whether gravitational waves carried energy that could be absorbed and in principle detected.

Comment: It might be good to highlight that the absorption and scattering rates are generally miniscule (e.g. $10^{-25}$ absorption ratio for a 100 Hz gravitational wave passing through Earth from the answer in the second link).

Comment: When a detector like LIGO measures a gravitational wave, doesn't some (very miniscule amount) of the wave's energy have to be transformed into the kinetic energy of the detector?